# How to create Role Membership rule which will validate "does not contains" condition in OIM

Tags: oim

I want to create Role Membership rule in OIM. I want to assign a role to user whose job title does not contain "xyz". If anybody knows how to achieve this please provide me the steps.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I read all the docs and i know how to create membership rule in OIM. But my requirement is assigning a role to user whose job title does not contains "xyz"(any String). OIM has 6 operators for creating expression in membership rule i.e. '=' , '!=', 'Contains', 'Starts With', 'Ends With','IN'. But it don't have 'Not Contains' operator. so how can I achieve this requirement .

Answer (score 2):

Since OIM UI do not have this capability, I have used JAVA API and implemented java code for creating membership rule. JAVA API has 'DOES_NOT_CONTAIN' operator and with the help of this I am able to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

OIM UI do not have this capability but can be achieved through OIM APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the expression builder in side rule generator. While creating the role you can add membership rule there you can see a option call does not contain.